# Would you retrieve result from external cache (Redis) asynchronously in scala Play Framework 2?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, redis, playframework-2.0

I'm pretty new in play + scala + non-blocking I/O world and I read everywhere that every request should be non-blocking I/O. But not sure whether I should go that way with retrieving cached data from different server? I am planning to host web application and Redis cache on a separate amazon servers and use cached data heavily.

Your opinions/expertise would be much appreciated.

Comment: FI, I guess you know this async redis driver https://github.com/etaty/rediscala

Comment: Good. I will check this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-blocking IO is all about optimal resource usage i.e untill the network/disk/other IO system is performing the IO operation we can do something else rather then waiting for it to complete.

In your case it does make sense to perform the IO on cache as non-blocking.

Comment: Would you still do in a non-blocking way even if you had many cache requests in a single web request? is there any danger to overuse async calls?

Comment: If the async calls are independent of each other than you should make overlapping calls and if the call B depends on result of call A then you have to make them sequential

Comment: is there a danger of overusing async calls?